# Need to find clinics with a given time slot free

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need a rails/mysql query to find those clinics which have a given time slot available

```
clinic.rb
has_many :appointments
id | name 
1 | Clinic A
2 | Clinic B

appointments
belongs_to :clinic
clinic_id | start_time       | end_time         | user_id
1         | 20 Jan 2016 12:00| 20 Jan 2016 13:00| 1
2         | 20 Jan 2016 13:00| 20 Jan 2016 14:00| 1
2         | 20 Jan 2016 16:00| 20 Jan 2016 18:00| 1
1         | 20 Jan 2016 15:00| 20 Jan 2016 18:00| 1
```

Now the user is going to give a time slot say 20 Jan 2016 13:00 to 13:30

In that time slot, I need to find clinics that are free for exactly that duration
Clinic B has an appointment from 13:00 to 14:00 so it is unavailable
Clinic A doesn't have any appointment, so it will give me that data

Similarly if the user selects 11:00 - 11:30 he will get both A and B

So given a time range, I need to figure out which clinic (if any) is free during the time

Comment: Why you data sample doesnt have year 2016 for starting date?

Comment: I made that sample data up. the 2015 in the query data was an accident

Answer (score 1):

You should solve this using the range overlap logic. You can find a nice explanation here

[Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4eea4/9)**

```
SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM clinic c
LEFT JOIN appoinment a
      ON c.`id` = a.`clinic_id`
     AND `start_time` < '2016-01-20 13:30:00'
     AND `end_time`   > '2016-01-20 13:00:00'
WHERE  `start_time` IS NULL;

SELECT c.*, a.*
FROM clinic c
LEFT JOIN appoinment a
      ON c.`id` = a.`clinic_id`
     AND `start_time` < '2016-01-20 11:30:00'
     AND `end_time`   > '2016-01-20 11:00:00'
WHERE  `start_time` IS NULL;
```

If you date overlap with any appointment you will have a matching join. Otherwise the time slot is free and you get `NULL`

Comment: I have to determine those clinics which donot have appointments in the given timeslot. How do I do that? Do you know ruby?

Comment: Time related questions are my kryptonite

Comment: Oh no I dont know ruby, This solve your question in MySQL. That isnt enough?

Comment: Check the demo again, I found one error. Try checking the result without the where is null so you see where are the overlaps